# How to achieve strictly file size limit in Abp

Tags: asp.net-web-api, file-upload, .net-5, abp

I'm trying to set **strictly file size limit** using filter, in the mean while, there is already a default global setting at `Startup.cs`

**Startup.cs**

```
int sizeLimit = 200000;

services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = sizeLimit;
});

services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = sizeLimit;
});

services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = sizeLimit);
```

**TestApiController.cs or Service(Dynamic Controller)**

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestApiController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [RequestSizeLimit(100_000)]
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 100_000)]
    public bool Post(IFormFile file)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I found **warning log** when i upload file

```
A request body size limit could not be applied. The IHttpRequestBodySizeFeature for the server is read-only.
```

I seem to need to set `IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature` `IsReadOnly` to false, but it can't. There's not setter at IsReadOnly.

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    var httpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature = context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>();
    httpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature.IsReadOnly = false;
});
```

Then I found it will affected by `IsUpgraded`, If  `IHttpUpgradeFeature.UpgradeAsync` be called will set `IsUpgraded` to `true`. I wonder this method may have called at somewhere, but i can't figure it out.

```
bool IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature.IsReadOnly => HasStartedConsumingRequestBody || IsUpgraded;
```

[ref IHttpUpgradeFeature.UpgradeAsync()](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/5c1fcd664d39db8fe5c8e38052a3cc29f90322f6/src/Kestrel.Core/Internal/Http/HttpProtocol.FeatureCollection.cs)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

need to use customized attribute
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/12336

Comment: Show the code instead of just a link.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).